# Windows 7 HP x64 - small cmd window

Tags: windows-7, fonts, cmd.exe

I've reinstalled my Windows 7 last time and few days ago my command prompt window suddenly became smaller (font 4x6 px). I simply changed the font and it works fine for command prompt window, but e.g. when I run xampp's or python's shell, it's still small. How can I restore the system defaults for command line?

Comment: Solved. Just find cmd.exe and change the font for it, not for command prompt window.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer when you'll be able to (you don't have enough reputation to do it right now).

Comment: There is no Font tab in a cmd.exe directly, only shortcuts contain it. So I don't know how to change font for all applications which use a new cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I restore the system defaults for command line?

You are using:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > Type "cmd" > Click "cmd" > Right click cmd window titlebar > Select "Properties"

You need to use "Defaults", modifying "Properties" only changes the current window.

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > Type "cmd" > Click "cmd" > Right click cmd window titlebar > Select "Defaults"